# I am creating a front end dashboard where I need to show all the posts by the current user. So, I need to show posts in publish

Tags: posts, publish, post-status

I am creating a front end dashboard where I need to show all the posts by the current user. So, I need to show posts in publish.

```
$post_status = 'draft';
```

I would like to use publish.

What should I do

Comment: What's your question exactly? Can you please clarify a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't understand the question perfectly, so I apologize, but,

```
$post_status = 'publish';
```

Wouldn't that do it?

I am missing context though, are you building a query? Because to get all the posts by the current user, something like this would be needed:

```
$args = array(
   "post_status" => "publish",
   "author" => get_current_user_id(),
   "posts_per_page" => 10
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
//do things with query...
```

Or are you working with query_posts or pre_get_posts? More context would be helpful here.